# Cannot save word document when VSTO addin is loaded

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, vsto

We developed a VSTO Word 2016 addin to connect to our server software. After getting a new machine, I cannot make it work again. When the Addin is loaded, I cannot save the word document anymore. If I close Word, it asks wether it should save the document, if I click "Yes", nothing happens. If I click File->Save As, I can click on "Browse" but nothing happens. WIthout the Addin, everything works.

To trace the problem down, I created a new blank VSTO addin. (New project -> Word VSTO plugin). Even with this minimal addin, the above behaviour appears.

I already reinstalled everything, same result. (Visual Studio 2017 Pro, Office 2016 Pro Plus, Windows 10 Pro 1809)

I am running out of ideas...

Comment: Is this happening in debug mode, as well? My best guess is that the problem is with the Word and/or Windows installation. First thing I'd try is to *repair* the Office installation. Then check ("google*) whether the installed  build of Windows has been causing any problems. There've been quite a few "interop hiccups" the last few months due to Windows updates - there was one last week in the Word+VSTO tag, although the problem behavior was different to what you describe. This sounds as if it could be a "security update weirdness".

Comment: Yes, this happens in debug mode as well. I repaired the office installation, no change. I also fear that is has something to do with "security update", but I cannot find anything on the web. The described behavior was already there after reinstalling windows+office+vs (without updates). After applying all updates, nothing changed.

Comment: Finally, I am not alone: [https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/cannot-save-word-files-after-1809-update/22b77d72-95f0-4610-afe9-45874c6c649f?page=1](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/cannot-save-word-files-after-1809-update/22b77d72-95f0-4610-afe9-45874c6c649f?page=1)